# Проблема с footer в шаблоне django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Нужно прикрепить динамически-изменяющийся футер к каждой странице сайта.

Я создал модель, чтобы можно было менять данные в футере через админку и добавил футер в шаблон для наследования другими страницами, сделав отдельный блок. В результате футер есть на каждой странице, но данные — только на главной.

Необходимо, чтобы футер со всеми постоянными и изменяющимися данными выводился на всех страницах.

***Шаблон футера (сделано с помощью `Bootstrap`):***

```html
{% block footer %}
  <footer class="page-footer font-small blue-grey lighten-5">
    <div style="background-color: #CD853F;">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row mt-3 dark-grey-text" style="padding-top: 20px;">
          <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 mb-4">
            <h6 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold" style="color: white;">Группа Вконтакте</h6>
            <hr class="teal accent-3 mb-4 mt-0 d-inline-block mx-auto" style="width: 60px;">
            <p style="color: white;">
              {% for main in mains %}
                {{ main.footer_vk }}
              {% endfor %}
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 mx-auto mb-4">
            <h6 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold" style="color: white;">Телефон</h6>
            <hr class="teal accent-3 mb-4 mt-0 d-inline-block mx-auto" style="width: 60px;">
            <p style="color: white;">
              {% for main in mains %}
                {{ main.footer_phone }}
              {% endfor %}
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 mx-auto mb-4">
            <h6 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold" style="color: white;">E-mail</h6>
            <hr class="teal accent-3 mb-4 mt-0 d-inline-block mx-auto" style="width: 60px;">
            <p style="color: white;">
              {% for main in mains %
                {{ main.footer_mail }
              {% endfor %}
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {% for main in mains %}
        <div class="footer-copyright text-center text-black-50 py-3">© {{ main.copyright }} Copyright:
          <a class="dark-grey-text" href="https://www.site-name.ru" style="color: white;">site-name.ru</a>
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
  </footer>
{% endblock %}
```

`Main` — класс, с помощью которого меняем данные в футере.

***models.py:***

```py
class Main(models.Model):
    header = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Заголовок на фотке')
    header_p = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name='Текст на фотке')
    footer_vk = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Группа вк')
    footer_mail = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Электронная почта')
    footer_phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Телефон')
    copyright = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Копирайт (год)')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего Вы не передаёте main из других функций или классов в контекст шаблона.Что бы сказать точно нужен Ваш код обработки запроса браузера из views.py для главной страницы и для любой другой которая не работает.

Comment: Спасибо, вставил main в представление каждой страницы, всё заработало. Вот из-за такого тупняка иногда и получаются косяки :)